# Azure SQL Managed Identities with App Service - is AD Authentication required for this? Is there a bicep file somebody can share?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice

I am really struggling regarding my Azure SQL configuration. I have an app I want to move from a prototype to production and I want to use Azure SQL Database with Managed Identities and SQL Authentication with App Services so I don't need to deal w/passwords. I was reading these two articles, [E2E DevOps for Azure SQL with Managed Identities](https://medium.com/medialesson/e2e-devops-for-azure-sql-with-managed-identities-f2231c7e964c) and [Secure Configuration in Azure with Managed Identity](https://jfarrell.net/2022/01/17/secure-configuration-in-azure-with-managed-identity/). This Microsoft document on [Azure Active Directory service principal with Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-service-principal?view=azuresql#troubleshooting-and-limitations) was referenced which referenced [Assign Azure AD roles to groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/groups-assign-role). As I was going through the latter and following along, I could not create assignments because I don't have AAD P1 or p2. Is that require? I am trying to do this all in bicep and wish there was a script for it. Does anybody have one?

The two articles referenced have additional components (DevOps integration for one and KeyVault/App Configuration for the other which might have complicated the explanations. I guess the key is accessing the database from App Service using Managed Identity. That alone would be helpful. I expect Azure AD Authentication is required for this but am not sure if that's the path that was chosen by the authors or if it was required?

I guess the other question is how to develop on my local machine if this is set up and I am not connecting through the Azure App Services Managed Identity.

Has anybody overcome all these questions to get this up and running?

Comment: Lots of different things here. you can grant a managed identity permission to azure sql through group or directly. Regarding developing locally if you use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and `Azure.Identity` packages (assuming you are using dotnet) you would be able to run the app locally if youve been granted permissions to the db as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication